# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}{\frac{1}{2(a-b)^2+ab}} \geq \frac{16(ab+bc+ca)^3(abc-1)}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}+3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> PROBLEM.Let $ a,b,c > 0$ such that $a+b+c=3$. Prove that
> $$\sum_{cyc}{\frac{1}{2(a-b)^2+ab}} \geq \frac{16(ab+bc+ca)^3(abc-1)}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}+3.$$

By AM-GM : $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2(a^2+b^2)-3ab} +16(a+b+c) \geq 42abc +9$$
Proof
$$42abc-16(a+b+c)+6 \geq \frac{16(ab+bc+ca)^3(abc-1)}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}\tag{$*$}$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c} \geq ab+bc+ca$$

Therefore $(*)$ is true by AM-GM. And we are done!

What other solutions are there?

Comment: Please show your attempt, or what you know about inequality!

Comment: And please make your tittle more specific by putting your question on the tittle.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I know this site can be a little lax on formality at times, but at the very least, please write in such a way that others would take you seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step leads to a wrong inequality.

It's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{16(1-abc)(ab+ac+bc)^3}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}\geq42(1-abc)$$ and since by AM-GM $1-abc\geq0,$ we need to prove that:
$$16(ab+ac+bc)^3\geq42(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}),$$ which is wrong for $b=c\rightarrow0^+$.

By the way, by C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a^2-3ab+2b^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{c^2}{c^2(2a^2-3ab+2b^2)}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(4a^2b^2-3a^2bc)}$$ and since by AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+1}{2}=3,$$ it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{9}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(4a^2b^2-3a^2bc)}+\frac{16(ab+ac+bc)^3(1-abc)}{3}\geq3,$$ which is true, but my proof of this statement is not nice.

I hope, it will help.

Comment: Nice (+1). I proved the last one by pqr method.

Comment: @River Li I don't see a nice solution. SOS is also very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\frac{1}{2(a-b)^2+ab}}
\ge \frac{(c + a + b)^2}{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} c^2(2a^2 + 2b^2 - 3ab)}. \tag{1}$$

By AM-GM, we have $abc \le (a + b + c)^3/27 = 1$
and $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt b + \sqrt c \le \frac{a + 1}{2} + \frac{b+1}{2} + \frac{c+1}{2} = 3$.

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{9}{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} c^2(2a^2 + 2b^2 - 3ab)} + \frac{16(ab + bc + ca)^3(1 - abc)}{3} \ge 3. \tag{2}$$

We use pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c = 3, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$.

(2) is written as
$$\frac{9}{4q^2 - 33r} + \frac{16q^3(1 - r)}{3} \ge 3. \tag{3}$$

Using $pq \ge 9r$ (by AM-GM), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{9}{4q^2 - 33r} + \frac{16q^3(1 - q/3)}{3} \ge 3. \tag{4}$$

We split into two cases.

**Case 1**: $q > 9/4$

Using degree three Schur, we have $p^3 - 4pq + 9r \ge 0$ which results in $r \ge 4q/3 - 3$.

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{9}{4q^2 - 33\cdot (4q/3 - 3)} + \frac{16q^3(1 - q/3)}{3} \ge 3$$
which is true.

**Case 2**: $q \le 9/4$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{9}{4q^2} + \frac{16q^3(1 - q/3)}{3} \ge 3$$
which is true.

We are done.